# postfix wrappermode depending on destination

Tags: postfix, starttls

My ISP accepts mail on port 465 thus requiring `smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes`. However, I also have another internal server, to which I forward mail on port 25 using `STARTTLS`, but with `smtp_tls_wrappermode = yes` `postfix` uses `SMTPS` protocol on transports to port 25, too.

Is there any way to configure `postfix` to only use wrapper mode for a specific relay host or only on port 465?

I've seen `smtp_tls_policy_maps` but apparently it only provides options for `smtp_tls_security_level` and cannot be used to specify wrapper mode, can it?

An obvious work-around would be to disable wrapper mode and use `stunnel` for the ISP, but I hope that there is some solution with less plumbing.